# Number Trouble with Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to filter a date retrieved from a .csv file, but no combination I try seems to work. The date comes in as "2011-10-01 19:25:01" or "year-month-date hour:min:sec".

I want just the year, month and date but I get can't seem to get ride of the time from the string:

```
date = bug[2] # Column in which the date is located  
date = date.replace('\"','') #getting rid of the quotations  
mdate = date.replace(':','')  
re.split('$[\d]+',mdate) # trying to get rid of the trailing set of number (from the time)
```

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your source is a string, you'd probably better use [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime)

```
import datetime
string = "2011-10-01 19:25:01"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

After that, use

```
dt.year
dt.month
dt.day
```

to access the data you want.

Comment: good idea, but I think the last line should be `dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks. I've corrected my code I've written too quickly

Comment: @JMax, it returns a ValueError: time data ' 2011-10-12 03:09:26' does not match format ...(the one in your code). Also thanks for the help

Comment: @Shahab: weird! I've tested the code in http://py-ide-online.appspot.com/ and it seems to work. Check you didn't add an extra space at the begining of your string (it exists in your comment)

Comment: There are quotations in the retrieved date so I removed them with the replace code above, but I see what your saying and am trying to see where I went wrong----> i got it to work!

Answer (score 6):

Use datetime to parse your input as a datetime object, then output it in whatever format you like: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the circumflex for start of line and dollar for end of line. Try `^[\d-]+`.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"`, then try this:

```
date = date[1:11]
```

In a prompt:

```
>>> date = '"2012-01-12 15:13:20"'
>>> date[1:11]
'2012-01-12'
>>>
```

No need for regex

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is that in your last regular expression, `$` matches the end of the string, so that regular expression will never match anything. You could do this much more simply by splitting by spaces and only taking the first result. After removing the quotation marks, the line

```
date.split()
```

will return `["2011-10-01", "19:25:01"]`, so the first element of that list is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> date = '"2011-10-01 19:25:01"'
>>> date.strip('"').split()[0]
'2011-10-01'
```